# ecpected primary expression before '/' token

Tags: c++

here is a segment of code where I get my error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

#define RAND_MAX
#define LWBND   0.0
#define UPBND   100.0
const int ARMAX = 100;
const int NUMperLINE = 7;
const int ARMIN = 20;

double randDouble()
    {
    srand(0);
    int num = rand();
    LWBND + ( num / ( RAND_MAX / ( UPBND - LWBND )))

    return double;
    }
```

the error occurs in the formula right before the return in the function. It says that it expected a primary funtion before the second '/', right after RAND_MAX. can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What is `RAND_MAX` defined to? Remember that the preprocessor works similar to query-replace in your editor, it replaces macros with their bodies. Now think about what happens if the body is *empty* (doesn't exist).

Comment: You're also missing a semicolon on the (useless-expression-)statement prior to your return statement, which will cause another compile-time error once you fix the one you're currently hitting.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on the semicolon, I totally missed that. As far as properly defining RAND_MAX, I'm not sure how to do that. My instructor never went over how to besides including the define statement at the top.

Comment: @MattV Tip: `<cstdlib>` [defines `RAND_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX). Your `#define` is clobbering that definition. Suggestion: remove your definition.

Comment: @MattV Also, side note: `using namespace std;` is a really bad practice to get into. If your instructor is suggesting you use it, that would (in my mind) cast serious doubt on everything else they say. Do what you need to do to pass the class, but keep in mind that it's bad practice.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `RAND_MAX` is defined by `cstdlib`. OP's code should raise an error due to attempting to redefine a macro.

Comment: I removed the #define for the RAND_MAX and it seems to have fixed the problem, at least there. I have a few smaller glitches to fix, but it's stuff I can handle. Thanks for all the help and tips. Also, my instructor also required that I define RAND_MAX, but that obviously won't work, so I'll tell them I can't define it.

Comment: You're just missing the value of your in the `#define` statement, i.e. `#define token [value]` as you do in the other lines.